# cURL download a file on a page where the URL changes but the link text does not

Tags: shell, curl, web-scraping, download

Kind of a newbie to cURL, trying to create a script that downloads a file provided on a webpage. The link to the file changes periodically, for example:

Day 1:

```
url-path-to-my-file-access_files.pl?id=82wxyy2rn4k2houeupymgk4ptvdw67sa
```

Day 2:

```
url-path-to-my-file-access_files.pl?id=jeqbreoazj6ys5mek375ujscp4hqmt92
```

However the link on the actual page is always "file.db" unfortunately the link also doesn't have a unique id or another tag to specify it.

Is there a way to tell cURL or another program to look for the link text "file.db" and grab the associated link in the href tag? Currently I have the script working where I can log in and download the file if I have the exact url (the ?id= part) but I need to find a way to determine that before I download the file.

Comment: You need to do 2 cURL fetches:  fetch the page, scrape the URL from it (search for the  "access_files.pl" and extract the ID), fetch the file.  So you need cURL + script code or something like grep.  If you need to authenticate first, then extra cURL steps and following cURL calls need to pass any session cookies set by authentication.

Comment: @DaveS Yeah I figured it'd be multiple cURL fetches, but there are multiple ?id= on the page, the page itself is access_files.pl, the file itself is the "jeqbreoazj6ys5mek375ujscp4hqmt92" junk. unfortunately the page doesn't add unique identifiers to the links, so the only unique identifier is the text in the <a>filename</a> tags, I'm just not sure how to grep for that but then grab the href tag for the link.

Comment: In a language like PHP I'd treat the page as a string and search on marker-substring 1 - n and know that ?id=(ID that I need) appears as the next ID after marker-substring n.  I don't do shell or grep coding so I can't help with those.  Finding unique marker-substrings tied to the ID you want depends on the page contents.

Comment: @DaveS Yeah i've given up using a combo of curl and grep and got it working in powershell ISE, it just throws a ton of errors outside of the ISE I need to figure out.

Comment: A command-line HTML parser like [tag:xidel] can help you. But without the webpage url/html-source I don't think anyone can help you.